# CSS: dynamic width of child elements to be fit the parent width

Tags: css, css-float

When writing CSS, I always find myself missing auto child width feature of floated child elements, to fit their total width to the parent's width.
In fact I find it hard to phrase in Google search box, so you may consider this example:
A `ul` contains four `li`
`li` has `float: left; list-style: none;` and because there are four `li` elements, each has `width: 25%;`
What if I want to make the number of `li` elements variable, instead of fixed *four*, so `li` gets width of 20% when they are *five*, or gets width of 10% if they are *ten*, or width of 50% when they are *two* etc..? Given that the `ul` has an explicit fixed width always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use css3's flex-box.

```
ul{display:box;}
li{box-flex:1;}
```

Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate(you may need to change -webkit to -moz or -o) http://jsfiddle.net/wKKte/

Comment: Didn't even know about this property, i'd say this is the way to go though. Backwards compatibility be damned.

Comment: That's exactly how I want it to work, you got the question, a selected answer candidate. But those prefixes implies it's not supported buy the majority of browsers out there. If only one can find a more standard method...

Comment: @Andreas Carlbom What did you mean by "Backwards compatibility" ? Was it your approach, the display:table that you consider outdated?

Comment: No, I meant that i prefer Gareth's approach, but that it isn't very backwards-compatible at all, since it's new in the CSS3 spec. My display: table is a bit more compatible, since IE8 at least, but as thirtydot helpfully pointed out, it failed spectacularly when the contents of the list items didn't have identical length.

Comment: @rahmanisback Yeah, unfortunately this only works in Webkit and Gecko currently. It's a shame because it fits the bill perfectly. Apparently IE10 will support it...

Answer (score 3):

Try display: table;

Here's a fiddle with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/7D5cM/